# How can change the links in TableConfig

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I would like to change the url in TableConfig.

I tried with adding ConfigModule.withConfig with routes but that does not work. Any idea ?

```
    ConfigModule.withConfig({
  cmsComponents: {
    ManageUsersListComponent: {
      component: CustomListComponent,
    },
    routing :{
      routes: {
        UserDetailsComponent: {paths: ['/custom/path'] }
      }
    }
  },
}),
```

Thx

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with type+Details

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
  routing :{
    routes: {
      'orgUserDetails': {
          paths: [listPath],
          paramsMapping,
      }
    }
  }
})
```